# Setting up php sessionclean cron job to run in chroot environment

Tags: php, cron

I have multiple PHP-FPM chroot sites that need to run the sessionclean cronjob. I found this gist here:

https://gist.github.com/zerthimon/4e15f4d04c888dee0410

Which has this edit of the /etc/cron.d/php file

```
*/30 * * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/www/pools ] && find /var/www/pools -path "*/var/lib/php5" -exec /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean {} $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) \;
```

First to note is that I am running php7, so php5 becomes php. Second note is that I have no maxlifetime in /usr/lib/php so am trying to run this without. Here is my modification which is not working:

```
 [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/www/html ] && find /var/www/html -path "*/var/lib/php" -exec /usr/lib/php/sessionclean {} \;
```

Can someone please tell me how to modify the above to parse through each /var/www/html/[chroot]/var/lib/php/sessions directory to remove sessionfiles that are not currently being used?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround. This does not directly modify the /etc/cron.d/php file, but does offer a solution for people wanting to clear session files no longer in use within chrooted php-fpm environments.

A tiny script runs every 4 hours in crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/html
for D in *; do
find /var/www/html/"$D"/var/lib/php/sessions/sess_* -mmin +240 -delete;
done
```

This will delete all session files not modified within the last 4 hours which are stored within each chroot environment.